# PuTTY connection error after NetworkManager changes

Tags: server, lubuntu, network-manager, vpn, openssh

I am using Ubuntu server 20.04. I switched network settings, changed Netplan to NetworkManager. This is required for L2TP/IPsec vpn connection using NetworkManager.
Further, after setting a static ip through NetworkManager, the ability to connect via ssh via PuTTY disappeared. When I try to connect via PuTTY I get the error "Network error: Connection timed out". How to fix the error?
Checking ssh and iptables status
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HSAI.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHvQq.jpg)

Comment: Hello. Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question.

Comment: You mention Ubuntu Server.. how does Lubuntu & the LXQt desktop fit in?  You also mention *network-manager* in tags which isn't used by Ubuntu Server installs (but is used by Lubuntu), so being clear on what changes you've made may also provide clues, and why you think the changes (*and thus your tags*) are involved. Was the Lubuntu manual helpful in this regard?

Comment: I switched network settings, changed Netplan to NetworkManager. This is required for L2TP/IPsec vpn connection using NetworkManager.

Comment: Was the [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/G/AdvancedNetworking.html) helpful ? as you've tagged you're using Lubuntu desktop.

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately no. I didn't find anything suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a split tunnel VPN so that traffic to the remote network goes over the VPN tunnel and everything else doesn't.

As you are using PuTTY, I'll assume you know how to use X11 forwarding with a X11 server, so are able to run the X11 `nm-connection-editor` GUI remotely.

In `nm-connection-editor` for the VPN connection, click on the IPv4 tab and then enable the "**Use this connection only for resources on its network**" checkbox.